# Linqpad result limitation of 10000 rows

Tags: linqpad

How do i increase the limitation of 10000 rows in linqpad to get more result rows. My query returns approximately 45000 rows. I tried editing the RoamingUserOptions.xml but the changes are reverted back to original state. Also used the Results to data grid option but no luck. Can anyone help me out??

Comment: Do you have the latest version? The "Results to Grid" option is limited only by memory. The limitation was removed sometime in April of 2012. Source: http://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1540003-increase-maximum-rows-returned-beyond-10000

Comment: Yes i do have the latest version. This is the code. from id in Products
where id.ProductsId.StartsWith("PId-1")
select new 
{
id.ProductsId
}
 i am getting a set of 9500 rows.. but it should return around 45k

Comment: So if you run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE SUBSTRING([ProductsId], 1, 5) = 'PId-1'` against your SQL server outside of LinqPad you get ~45,000 rows?

Comment: I havent done that. I have ODATA and used powerpivot excel function to extract data from odata. I selected productsid and the number of rows where ~45k...

Comment: Now I found it, the Results to Grid option wasn't obvious to me and took a bit of hunting around to find it. Now that I know it's there it makes LinqPad even more useful. One of my coworkers and was also surprised about the feature and delighted as well once I told her.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Cory pointed out, in "Results to Grid" mode, LINQPad will give you all rows - or throw an OutOfMemoryException.

The most likely reason for getting fewer is that the OData server is configured with a limit on how many it will return per query.

Comment: If the OData server is configured with a limit will that limit apply to Excel PowerPivot because in excel I am getting the total number of rows? Also is there a way to find out whether the Odata has the limit on it?